# Calculating time complexity when number of elements is not given in algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, complexity-theory, time-complexity, recurrence

I want to find the data at i'th position from end in a linked list. I have written this code using recursion :

NODE STRUCTURE :

```
struct Node
{
   int data;
   struct Node * next;
}
```

CODE :

```
int i = 10;

int find ( Node * ptr, unsigned int count )
{
   if( nullptr == ptr )
   {
      ++ count;
      return count;
   }

   count = find ( ptr->next , count );
   if( i == count )
   {
      std::cout << "Successful here: " << ptr->data << std::endl; 
      exit ( -1 ) ;
   }

   else
   {
      ++ count;
      return count ;  
   }
}
```

I have basic idea about calculating time complexities using recurrence relations. But I am not able to write the relation itself. Can some one give a direction ?

From what I understand, I am dividing the problem to one less elements each time (by moving to the next node).

So it should be something like

T(n) = T(n-1) + Constant

Could Tree method or any other method be any better in such a situation ?

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly simple.

You already have the sequence for your time complexity with

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + Constant
```

What you also need are your end condition.
The first is you find element n.
The second is your array has only m element where m < n.

So since your `count` is increasing for every iteration we have to change the time complexity sequence a bit to

```
T(i,c) = T(i-c, c+1) + Constant
```

This is because you declared i to be the index you want to find.

So now for the first end condition we can write

```
T(0,i) = Constant
```

And for the second end condition is exactly the same as `T(m,0)` so if i > m we just switch i to m for the complexity.

Now lets assume that Constant is equal to 1.

Then we get the following equation

```
T(i,0) = T(i-0,1) +1 = T(i-1,2) +2 = T(i-2,3) +3 = T(i-3,4) +4 = .... = i+1
```

So the complexity is `T((min(i,m),0) = i+1` or `T(i,0)` is in `O(i)`.

You could change your code to

```
int find ( Node * ptr, unsigned int i ){
       if( nullptr == ptr )
          return i;

       if( i == 0 )
       {
          std::cout << "Successful here: " << ptr->data << std::endl; 
          return 0;
       }
       return find ( ptr->next , --count );
    }
```

So you would then have the sequence `T(n) = T(n-1) + Constant`